# Trying to get a single value from stdClass Object containing nested stdClass Objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I am being returned a response from an API method, and I simply need to get the value of "CustomerContactIdentifier".

I have tried interating through, but just getting foreach errors.

Any help on this would be appriciated.

```php
stdClass Object
(
    [CreateCustomerContactResponse] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CreateCustomerContactResult] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CustomerContactIdentifier] => 4975
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You can access object properties by using `->` e.g. `$obj->prop` .Same for chained objects

Comment: The foreach should be used for arrays not objects. Show us your code

Comment: @Claudio This is what I have been trying. `$obj->CreateCustomerContactResponse->CreateCustomerContactResult->CustomerContactIdentifier;`

Comment: @Richard is `CreateCustomerContactResponse` and `CreateCustomerContactResult` custom PHP classes? If yes, can you post the code

Answer (score 0):

You can access a value using as follows

```
    $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CreateCustomerContactResponse xmlns="http://www.*******.com"><CreateCustomerContactResult><CustomerContactIdentifier>5081</CustomerContactIdentifier></CreateCustomerContactResult></CreateCustomerContactResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
    $response = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response); $response = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response);
    $parser = simplexml_load_string($response);

    $result = json_decode(json_encode($parser));

    echo $result->CreateCustomerContactResponse->CreateCustomerContactResult->CustomerContactIdentifier;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: What if those properties are private?

Comment: Thats exactly what I have been trying but its not getting the value!!

Comment: @Claudio this is the api response , how can the variable be private ?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar it could be mapped into objects. But it seems to be simple `stdClass` objects

Comment: Thanks for all you comments. Am still battling here. The response that comes back from the API is XML
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CreateCustomerContactResponse xmlns="http://www.*******.com"><CreateCustomerContactResult><CustomerContactIdentifier>5081</CustomerContactIdentifier></CreateCustomerContactResult></CreateCustomerContactResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Comment: I then remove the soap tags
`$response = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);` 
`$response = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response); `
and then
`$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);`
and then
`$result = json_decode(json_encode($parser), true);`

Comment: Remove true from the statement $result = json_decode(json_encode($parser), true);
Corrected statement $result = json_decode(json_encode($parser));

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values by using `->`

```
$object->CreateCustomerContactResponse->CreateCustomerContactResult->CustomerContactIdentifier;
```

See the example here : https://3v4l.org/5npki

OR

You can convert `object` to an `array`

```
 $a = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
echo $a['CreateCustomerContactResponse']['CreateCustomerContactResult']['CustomerContactIdentifier'];
```